# UITextField is null after callI textfield.text.length

Tags: ios

I have 3 textfields in a xib which is added as a subview to the main view. When i press a button to perform a function the text is pulled from the fields and all works as it should.

However if i press the button again the textfields return null.

Heres the code

.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *targetZ;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *targetY;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *targetX;
```

.m

```
- (IBAction)performScan:(id)sender {

[targetZ resignFirstResponder];
[targetY resignFirstResponder];
[targetX resignFirstResponder];

NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@",targetZ.text,targetY.text,targetX.text);

   if (selectedScanID > 0) {

    if (targetX.text.length != 0) {
        if (targetY.text.length != 0) {
            if (targetZ.text.length != 0) {
                [self launchScan];

            }else {
                NSLog(@"Please Enter Z Coordinate");
            }
        }else {
            NSLog(@"Please Enter Y Coordinate");
        }
    }else {
        NSLog(@"Please Enter X Coordinate");
    }
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Select Scan First");
}

}

-(void) launchScan {

Globals *sharedManager = [Globals sharedManager];

NSString *weburl =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:XXXXXXXXX/performScan.php?token=%@&type=%d&x=%@&y=%@&z=%@",sharedManager.token,selectedScanID,targetX.text,targetY.text,targetZ.text];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:weburl];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                           NSData *testdata, NSError *connectionError) {

                           if (testdata.length > 0 && connectionError == nil) {


                               NSArray *theResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:testdata
                                                                                     options:0
                                                                                       error:NULL];


                               NSLog(@"%@",theResults);

                               NSDictionary *dic = [theResults objectAtIndex:4];
                               int amps = [[dic objectForKey:@"amps"]intValue];
                               int sRoids = [[dic objectForKey:@"totalRoids"]intValue];
                               dic = [theResults objectAtIndex:3];
                               int tRoids = [[dic objectForKey:@"totalRoids"]intValue];
                               int blocks = [[dic objectForKey:@"blocks"]intValue];

                               int chance = 30. * (1 + amps/sRoids - blocks/tRoids);

                               chance = 1000 * chance;
                               if ( chance >= 99990) chance =  99990;
                               if ( chance <= 10) chance = 10;

                               int rVal = arc4random() % 100000;

                               if (rVal < chance) {
                                   NSLog(@"SUCCESS");
                                   scanResult = 1;
                                   if ( (rVal + selectedScanID * 5000) > chance ) {
                                       NSLog(@"NOTICED");
                                       scanResult = 2;
                                   }
                               }
                               else {
                                   NSLog(@"BLOCKED");
                                   scanResult = 3;
                               }

                               [self showScan];

                           }

                       }

 ];

}

-(void) showScan {

if (scanResult == 8) {
    //Show Scan

    NSArray *xibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"wavesXIB" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *view = [xibContents objectAtIndex:2];

    [self.view addSubview:view];
}

if (scanResult == 9) {
    //Show Scan
    //Noticed
    NSArray *xibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"wavesXIB" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *view = [xibContents objectAtIndex:2];

    [self.view addSubview:view];
    NSLog(@"Noticed");
}

if (scanResult > 0) {
    NSArray *xibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"wavesXIB" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *blockedView = [xibContents objectAtIndex:3];
    blockedView.center = [self.view convertPoint:self.view.center fromView:self.view.superview];


    [blockedView setAlpha:0.0];
   [self.view addSubview:blockedView];
  //  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
   //     [blockedView setAlpha:1.0];
  //  }];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.f delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        [blockedView setAlpha:1.f];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.f delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            [blockedView setAlpha:0.f];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            [blockedView removeFromSuperview];


        }];
    }];


    NSLog(@"Blocked");
}

}
```

The text is still visible in the fields and doesn't change.

Comment: Please clarify. Do the text fields themselves return null or do the textfields `.text` return null?

Comment: In other words, you might want to add more logging, e.g. `NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@",targetZ,targetY,targetX)` - now, what's really null here?

Comment: i get the log "Please enter x coordinate" so targetX.text.length is returning nil

Comment: Also, what does `launchScan` do?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@",targetZ,targetY,targetX); on first press it recognises the textfields, on second press i get null null null

Comment: There you go. So if `targetZ` is null, `targetZ.text` is null, and `targetZ.text.length` is null. That is how to debug. You are learning!

Comment: So now you need to figure out who is setting your `targetZ` and so on to null.

Comment: launchScan performs a GET request using the text inputted from the textfield

Comment: Try NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@",self.targetZ.text,self.targetY.text,self.targetX.text);

Comment: "I have 3 textfields in a xib which is added as a subview to the main view" Okay, that sounds vaguely illegal. It is probably the source of your problem! Please show the code by which you obtain this xib and add it to the main view.

Comment: self.targetX.text also returns null on second press.

Comment: Right, I think it's the `wavesXIB` loading-and-dumpster-diving that is the problem.

Comment: Why are you doing that? It is profoundly weird. I think when you do that it is resetting your outlets to nil. And there is no need for it; I think it is based on some kind of misconception. Can you explain what you think you're up to?

Comment: wavesXIB contains 4 UIViews 3 which are used in the main view, and 1 for when the scan is blocked, its just a UIImageView to say scan is blocked, the view that is used will depend on the result of performScan

Comment: Okay, but there is no need for that, and I think it's unwise to say the least. However, let that go for a moment. Please change `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"wavesXIB" owner:self options:nil]` so that `owner` is nil. See if that fixes the whole problem.

Comment: The view with the textfields is in wavesXIB at index 0, and is only called once with viewdidload

Comment: You have a main view controller, right? So it should have a view. So all the views you need should be subviews of this. Then everything is loaded automatically. Then you can just show or hide them as needed. Do you understand about view controllers and their main views? You should not be manually loading xibs like this; there is no need.

Comment: "is only called once with viewdidload" No, you're wrong. I can see you doing it again in `showScan` and I am saying that this is the whole source of your problem.

Comment: Im using CollapseClick which is like a collapsable uitableview, to populate the sections i have to pass in a UIView for each section.

Comment: When changing owner to nil it crashes *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x146a5cc0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key scanSelectButton.'

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem, I think, is that you are performing what I call "dumpster-diving" in a xib without taking full account of the consequences. I will attempt to explain my guess.

You have a `.xib` file `wavesXIB`. It contains outlet connections. This means that when it is loaded with an owner, it sets instance variables in that owner. I think this might explain why your instance variables pointing at the text fields work the first time but not subsequently: you load the xib again and this accidentally sets the the instance variables to text fields again. But you do not, as you originally did, put those text fields into your interface. But your instance variables are `weak` references! So there is no memory management. *Therefore the text fields instantly vanish in a puff of smoke* and you are left with nil references.

The real point is that you should not be manually diving into a xib this way, especially not with `self` as owner, because the nib-loading process affects the owner.

If you really want to keep doing things this way, use more nibs. When you load `wavesXIB` the second time its outlets are having an unwanted side effect. So draw your extra views at that time from a different nib that has no outlets (you don't need outlets because you are just grabbing the views from the resulting array of loaded instances).

I would suggest, however, that you completely eliminate this way of doing this. Just use a normal view controller and it will have a normal main view which will be automatically loaded from its nib in the normal way. Have it contain all of the interface you will ever need. You can always have some views be hidden, and show them (`hidden = NO`) whenever they are needed.

Comment: And you might want to read my full discussion of the nib-loading mechanism here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_nib_loading_and_file_8217_s_owner

Comment: And I'm a bit worried that you don't understand view controllers and how important it is to use them, and use them properly; maybe you do, but in any case here's my discussion: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html